# Error while creating AzureResourceGroup Project in visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, azure-resource-group

When trying to create Azure Resource Group project I get the following error

> An error occurred while sending the request

Steps to reproduce:
File>New>Project>Cloud> Select "Azure Resource Group" Project Click "OK". It shows "Creating Project" then the error comes "An error occurred while sending the request"

I have tried to do a repair. Also I have done uninstall and reinstall of VS2017

Is there anything else I can do or where I can see the error log for this.

When running it with fiddle noticed that it called 
azurermtoolsprod.blob.core.windows.net:443 
this is giving 503 http code. 
When I connect to my US VPN the URL works and Azure Resource Group project works.
From India it does not

Comment: Have you taken a look at this guide? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/vs-azure-tools-resource-groups-deployment-projects-create-deploy

Comment: I have been using the above link for a long time. The place it fails is. File>New>Project>Cloud> Select "Azure Resource Group" Project Click "OK". It shows "Creating Project" then the error comes "An error occurred while sending the request" no project is created.